# Editing MosaicDataset attributes

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcobjects

I am trying to access and edit a MosaicDataset (I need to edit the MaxPS/MinPS fields) but I cannot find a way to access them programmatically.

Does anyone know how can I edit these fields?